# CP850 Sybase Arabic in PHP

Tags: php, sybase, iconv

I have a client that do use Sybase database on one of his servers , and i was asked to develop an application with PHP 7.1 that use this particular database to Select some information, hardly found a suitable drive = dblib the database use charset cp850 and varchar columns i have no hand or option to change any thing in the database the columns that contain Arabic language when i do retrieve appears (????) so i did use in PHP the following Connection string

```
return  new PDO ("dblib:host={$ip}:5000;dbname={$this->settings['db']};charset=cp850","username","password");
```

and with the following in the view to print the result `{{iconv('windows-1256','utf-8',$shipper['owner_name'])}}`

the ??? was changed to another near to Arabic â/„àئگ but still not Arabic What can i do use or change?
I did use Ubuntu OS , Laravel Frame Work 5.4 , PHP 7.1 and non of them or the Syabse could change the only thing that am able to do is change to my code to avoid the problem of the binary data that is stored in the database Varchar columns

Comment: Decoding as cp850 may actually be damaging the data.

Comment: CP850 doesn't support Arabic characters. The database cannot make the conversion and most probably returns mangled data, which you then feed to iconv telling it that it's actually Windows-1256 (which does support Arabic characters, but the input *isn't* Windows-1256), so there's no way in which this can work.

Comment: i have no hand on the database i just have a remote connection and offer to do changes in the database but its not possible for him

Comment: Bottom line is, if you don't know what encoding the data in the database is actually in, you cannot make this conversion work. Sybase appears to support specifying `cp1256` as the character set in the connection string : if the data is actually encoded in Windows-1256, this might just work.

Comment: Then What is the suitable approach to solve that problem from the database or what can i do to handle the query even the query result is the same

Comment: are other applications able to retrieve arabic from the database? if so, what character set are they using with their application? have you tried replacing `charset=cp850` with `charset=cp1256` like @daniel suggested?

Comment: change it at the connection string and the iconv and got the same result, note when i did not use iconv the result print is nothing !!!!